# SetInterval() within setInterval() at different times

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I would like to ask how is it possible to run a function every 60 seconds which has another timer inside it that only runs every 5 minutes

```
function systemTime() {
  let currentTime = new Date();
  let diem = "AM";
  let h = currentTime.getHours();
  let m = currentTime.getMinutes();
  let s = currentTime.getSeconds();

  if (h == 0) h = 12;
  if (h > 12) diem = "PM";
  if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
  if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
  if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;

  return {
     h: h.toString(),
     m: m.toString(),
     diem: diem
  }
}


async function serverTime() {
  let timeUrl = 'https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe';
  let response = await fetch(timeUrl);
  let data = await response.json();

  let timestamp = data.datetime;
  let time = timestamp.split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
  let timeArray = time.split(':');
  if(parseInt(timeArray[0]) > 12) timeArray[2] = 'PM'
  else timeArray[2]  = 'AM';

  return {
    h: timeArray[0],
    m: timeArray[1],
    diem: timeArray[2]
  }
}

async function clock() {
  let h, m, diem;
  let container = document.querySelector('#displayClock');
  container.innerHTML = `${h} : ${m}`;
  setInterval(() => clock(), 60000);
  // I would like to grab the server time every 5 min for comparison
  setInterval(() => {}, 60000*5) // set minutes and hours to the server time 

}
```

I would like to call the clock() function every 60s to display the time on a page but at the same time I would like to call the serverTime() function every 5 minutes to compare the values and take the serverTime if they are not the same.

Calling clock() every 60s isn't the problem. setInterval will solve this but if within it I set an Interval of 5 min then every 10 seconds there will be a new 5 min interval set?

Thankyou very much for your help.

Comment: Where are you using `setInterval`?  If you can set an interval for every 60 seconds (60000 ms), why can't you set one for every 5 minutes (300000 ms)?

Comment: @David I have added the set interval to the code. But if the clock will run every 1 min will it not set a new 5 min interval every 1 min?

Answer (score 2):

You are *recursively* setting intervals:

```
async function clock() {
  //...
  setInterval(() => clock(), 60000);
  setInterval(() => {}, 60000*5);
}
```

So every time you call `clock` (every minute), you are setting more and more intervals for both `clock` and, well, an empty function.  (It looks like you forgot to try to call `serverTime`?)

If you want to call `clock` every 60 seconds, then just set an interval to call it every 60 seconds:

```
async function clock() {
  //...
}

setInterval(clock, 60000);
```

If you want to call `serverTime` every 5 minutes, then just set an interval to call it every 5 minutes:

```
async function serverTime() {
  //...
}

setInterval(serverTime, 300000);
```

There's no need to do this recursively.  Doing so means that *setting an interval* is part of the operation being repeated, which isn't what you want.

**Edit:** To demonstrate the problem, watch your browser console on this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Laqt4oe5  How many times do you expect the number to increase every 3 seconds?  How many times is it actually increasing?

Comment: I still don't understand what the trouble in the question is

Comment: @Tân: If the `clock` function itself sets the interval to call the `clock` function then consider what happens every 60 seconds.  First there's an interval to call `clock` every minute, then there are 2 intervals to call `clock` every minute, then there are 4, then 8, and so on.  Before long the code is calling the `clock` function dozens, hundreds, etc. of times every minute.

Comment: So, I think the question should be edited to: *How to use setInterval in javascript?* instead of *How to use nested setInterval(s) right way?*

Comment: @Tân: I suspect the OP may just be confused on exactly what `setInterval` does, and is perhaps mistaking it for `setTimeout` (which would need to be called recursively to mimic the behavior of an interval).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to solve the issue and obtain what i wanted

/**
 * Display a digital clock
 * 
 * @param {string} container - placement of the clock on the page
 */

```
function systemTime() {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    let diem = "AM";
    let h = currentTime.getHours();
    let m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    let s = currentTime.getSeconds();

    if (h == 0) h = 12;
    if (h > 12) diem = "PM";
    if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
    if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
    if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;

    return {
        h: h.toString(),
        m: m.toString(),
        diem: diem
    }
}

/**
 * Returns an object containing hours and minutes from the worldTimeAPI
 */
async function serverTime() {
    let timeUrl = 'https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin';
    let response = await fetch(timeUrl);
    let data = await response.json();

    let timestamp = data.datetime;
    let time = timestamp.split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
    let timeArray = time.split(':');
    if(parseInt(timeArray[0]) > 12) timeArray[2] = 'PM'
    else timeArray[2]  = 'AM';

    console.log('Time fetched from world API');

    return {
        h: timeArray[0],
        m: timeArray[1],
        diem: timeArray[2]
    }
}

/**
 * Fires every 5 min and compares server and system times
 */
async function compareTime() {
    let server = await serverTime();
    let system = systemTime();
    let container = document.querySelector('#displayClock');
    if(system.h != server.h || system.m != server.m) container.innerHTML = `${server.h} : ${server.m} ${server.diem}`;
    else container.innerHTML = `${system.h} : ${system.m} ${system.diem}`;
    setInterval(() => compareTime(), 60000);
}

/**
 * Fires every 1 min and displays system time
 */
function displayTime() {
    let system = systemTime();
    let h = system.h;
    let m = system.m;
    let diem = system.diem;
    let container = document.querySelector('#displayClock');
    container.innerHTML = `${h} : ${m} ${diem}`;
    setInterval(() => displayTime(), 60000);
}
```